# Is it possible to get exchange to look at multiple calendars for scheduling?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Is it possible to have exchange look in multiple calendars when determining my availability for meetings?

Comment: Are you talking about when other people try to invite you?  Or just when you are scheduling your own meetings?

Comment: when other people try to invite me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in support for this.

However, there are several software packages that allow you to do a one way sync with multiple calendars to pull in entries to your primary calendar.